# Text completion suggestion in emacs

Tags: completion

Emacs has been favorite editor for more than twenty five years but it looks like one feature is missing. That one is text completion suggestions.

In most of the editors once you start typing, it keeps suggesting the completions. Sometimes, these are based on previous sessions, sometimes based on common words applicable to the current mode. Notepad++ is one notable example.

A quick search did not reveal any such feature package for emacs.

Do you think that you can suggest something?

Answer (score 4):

Look into ["company mode"](http://company-mode.github.io/) perhaps. It is not built in but it will give you a dropdown of completions. You can choose how those completions are filled in by using different backends.

There is also dabbrev-expand which is built in and will autocomplete the text before the point with code that you had typed previously in the buffer by default it is bound to `M-/` you can hit it multiple times to cycle through completetions.

Some modes also provide something called `completion-at-point` which is bound to `C-M-i` by default

Answer (score 4):

The most popular package seems to be [company mode](http://company-mode.github.io/).  From the README:

> Company is a modular completion mechanism.  Modules for retrieving completion candidates are called back-ends, modules for displaying them are front-ends.
>
> Company comes with many back-ends, e.g. `company-elisp'.  These are
> distributed in separate files and can be used individually.

So depending on what types of files you are editing, you will need to grab the appropriate front-end/back-end tools that use the `company` framework.  For example, for C/C++ you could look at [irony](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) and its accompanying backend [company-irony](https://github.com/Sarcasm/company-irony).